# Changing the shape of Censored Events using the survminer package (ggsurvplot) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

i'm using the survminer package to create a Kaplan-Meier-Curve in R, which is working pretty well:

```
plotUICC=survfit(Surv(as.numeric(myData$eventtime),event=myData$eventtype)~myData$UICC, data = myData)

ggsurvplot(plotUICC,data=myData, risk.table = FALSE,pval = TRUE,conf.int = FALSE,legend.labs = c("UICC I", "UICC II"),legend = c(0.25, 0.26),legend.title = "",xlab = "Time in Months"))
```

[Kaplan Meier Curve created with the Cod above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otQFR.png)

I would like to change the "+" as censored event and use an simple "|" instead. Unfortunately neither help(ggsurvplot) nor google could help me.

---

These are the loaded packeges:

```
    other attached packages:
[1] ggthemes_3.4.0  survminer_0.3.1 ggpubr_0.1.2    ggplot2_2.2.1   survival_2.40-1
[6] readxl_0.1.1    gridExtra_2.2.1
```

Comment: Can you expand your question by providing a minimum working example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal working example is the following:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)
```

Ideally, one would like to change the shape of the censors e.g. like so:

```
p2 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, censor.shape=124)
```

I have found no way to do this with the original survminer package. In a [fork](https://github.com/mingrisch/survminer) of survminer , I have implemented this behaviour, so that the following plot is produced:

[image]

Acceptable values for censor.shape can be found here:
http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but this extension is already very useful for me. The "+" censors have bothered me for some time...

Edit: This suggestion was now merged, the [development version](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer) of ggsurvplot now accepts censor.shape and censor.size arguments:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, censor.shape="|", censor.size = 4)
```