# Remove dash on strata line when using ggsurvplot and survminer

Tags: r, survival, survminer

How do I change the line type for the sex strata so that it is a line without all the small "crosses" as shows in the picture below? I hope to get just a solid line instead. The cross makes things look a little congested when there is a lot of data points.

```
library(survminer)


fit <- survfit( Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon )
ggsurvplot(fit, colon,
                palette = "jco", pval = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set `censor=FALSE`.

```
library(survminer)
library(survival) # to obtain the colon dataset

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon)
ggsurvplot(fit, colon, censor = FALSE,
           palette = "jco", pval = TRUE)
```

[image: survival_plot]

If you search the help of `ggsurvplot`, you will find there are more parameters to customize the censored events:

### Censor points

- **censor**: logical value. If TRUE (default), censors will be drawn.
- **censor.shape**: character or numeric value specifying the point shape of censors. Default value is "+" (3), a sensible choice is "|" (124).
- **censor.size**: numeric value specifying the point size of censors. Default is 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

These are *censoring events* and it is normally expected that you show them on a survival curve. If you *really* want to get rid of them (and I don't see an option to do this directly within `ggsurvplot`), you can remove the layer they are in after the plot is created. Here's a reprex:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)

fit <- survfit( Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon )
g <- ggsurvplot(fit, colon, palette = "jco", pval = TRUE)

g$plot$layers[[3]] <- NULL

g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the argument `censor.shape` with NA like this:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)
fit <- survfit( Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon )
ggsurvplot(fit, colon,
           palette = "jco", pval = TRUE,
           censor.shape=NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249994/changing-the-shape-of-censored-events-using-the-survminer-package-ggsurvplot-i) with some useful links.

For more information and options check the **Censor points** part in the [documenation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.4.9/topics/ggsurvplot)

Comment: Ah, so there _is_ an option. Where is this documented @Quinten?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, Please check the link in my answer, which has an explanation.

Comment: @AllanCameron, It is described at the Censor points part of the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.4.9/topics/ggsurvplot)

Comment: Ah, found it. Strange it's not listed with the other parameters.